Filepond & Nextjs: How revalidate or even cache the XMLHttpRequest in Nextjs?
As you might know, Nextjs automatically caches the response of a fetch method and its 'force-cache' by default, But I'm using Filepond with react adaptor, and I can't cache, tag, or revalidate anything since Filepond is using XMLHttpRequest to track the progress percentage, aborting and lots more which is impossible to do with fetch
here is how FilePond works:

process: (fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort, transfer, options) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(fieldName, file, file.name);

  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', '/api/docs');

  // Should call the progress method to update the progress to 100% before calling load
  // Setting computable to false switches the loading indicator to infinite mode
  request.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
    progress(e.lengthComputable, e.loaded, e.total);
  };

  // Should call the load method when done and pass the returned server file id
  // this server file id is then used later on when reverting or restoring a file
  // so your server knows which file to return without exposing that info to the client
  request.onload = function () {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      // the load method accepts either a string (id) or an object
      load(request.responseText);
    } else {
      // Can call the error method if something is wrong, should exit after
      error('oh no');
    }
  };

  request.send(formData);

  // Should expose an abort method so the request can be canceled
  return {
    abort: () => {
      // This function is entered if the user has tapped the cancel button
      request.abort();

      // Let FilePond know the request has been canceled
      abort();
    },
  };
},

you can read more in this link
and since nextjs didn't extended XMLHttpRequest like fetch():
await fetch("/api/docs", {
        next: { tags: ['docs'] },
        cache: 'force-cache'
});

I can't cache or tag it to revalidate it in my API route.
I am using nextjs version 14.2.3 right now and I know it's a feature that nextjs needs to add but I want to know if anyone solved it...
